# Which is the auxiliary verb and modal?

Tags: grammar

> It is being used.

Considering the sentence above, I wonder which part is helping verb.

Comment: Please rewrite your question so it is obvious what the text of the sentence is you are asking about and what the text of the question is

Answer (score 1):

'is' is the auxiliary verb in your sentence.

Auxiliary verbs can be used when giving short answers to questions as well.

For example,

Q: Is it being used ?

A: Yes, it is. ('is' is the auxiliary verb)

You might find the below link useful.

http://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/what-are-auxiliary-verbs